# Socket.io client instantly disconnecting

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

When I restart the server, the client fails to connect. After I refresh, the client connects for a brief moment before disconnecting (almost instant). What could be the issue?

I've looked into solutions for "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=RP8fTjaNwFpoh4D2AAAC." but it doesn't seem to be just Firefox — Chrome and Safari both yield the exact same results. Another thing I noticed is when I edit my client-side code and save, it appears to allow the socket.io client to connect until I refresh the page which will trigger in order: disconnect, connect, disconnect.

Client Code:

```
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000");
React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data.message));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
      setTime(data);
    });
    socket.on("connect", data => {
      setTime(data);
      console.log('socket connected');
      console.log(socket.id)
    })
    socket.on("reconnect_failed", () => {
      console.log(socket.disconnected)
    });
    return () =>
      socket.disconnect();
  }, [])
```

Server Code:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000"
    }
});

let interval;
let socket_id;
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket_id = socket.id;
    console.log(socket.id, "connected");
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    interval = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket), 1000);
    socket.on("joingame", (data) => {
        console.log("connected to game");
        // too many connecting in terminal logs
    })
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        if (cd_current != "" && gd_current != "") {
            sql_db.handleDisconnect(cd_current, gd_current, socket_id);
        }
        console.log(cd_current);
        console.log(`Client ${socket_id} disconnected`);
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
```